# Is it possible to securely pass variable from JavaScript to Flash app?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, security, browser

How secure - by design - is the [ExternalInterface API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) call between JavaScript and Flash app residing in the same HTML container (on client side)?

**Can it be - by design - intercepted?**

Hint: the ExternalInterface API reference (above) reads

> The ExternalInterface class requires the user's web browser to support
>   either **ActiveX®** or the **NPRuntime** API that is exposed by some browsers
>   for plug-in scripting. See
>   http://www.mozilla.org/projects/plugins/npruntime.html.

Thanks

Comment: @David you would need a key to do that. To store a hardcoded key in the Flash app makes no sense (it can be decompiled)

Comment: If it runs on the client, it can be intercepted.

Comment: @zzzzBovm can you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by intercepted?  If you trust the page / sandbox that the `ExternalInterface` call is being made to then it is secure.  The only attack vector I could think of would be the hacker modifying the `__flash__toXML` javascript function.

Another point worth noting is that [`ExternalInterface.call` is vulnerable to XSS attacks](http://lcamtuf.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/other-reason-to-beware-of.html); so the arguments must always be sanitized if they are coming from the user.

Comment: Thanks Jonny, the variable will come form a backend, not from the user, but thanks for the link, it's very interesting. What does it mean to "to modify the __flash__toXML javascript function"? Can it be prevented? Thanks

Comment: I wonder just how hackable these are.  I'm not doing so much flash these days, but it could provide to be an interesting XSS exploit.  As always tho, if you can trust the HTML page then you should be good to go - just bear in mind that all data will be sent in the clear so will be visible to that user.